# Did Adam commit an act of Ahavas Yisroel or self-sacrifice to eat from the Tree of Knowledge?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, adam

I've seen on non-Jewish websites explaining the fact that Adam ate from the tree was because he loved Eve more than he loved God, or that he did an act of self-sacrifice so that Eve wouldn't suffer alone. Is there any source in Judaism that discusses this possible angle?

Comment: Your title mentions Ahavas Yisroel and your question asks about Ahavas Eve. Which do you want to know

Comment: @robev either or both. Any.

Comment: Five minutes later he blames "the woman" when God takes him to task, rather than accept responsibility. Makes it hard to believe he ate out of concern for her.